# Line return/spacing after \hrulefill

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, vertical-alignment

I'm new to LaTeX and am trying to make a simple resume.  I'd like my left-justified name to appear above an `\hrulefill` line followed by my right-justified address on the next line.

However, when I do this there is a large return space that I can't seem to remove above my address.  I can get the name to be directly on top of the line with `\nointerline` skip after my name but get errors when trying to use this after the line.

btw: Because I'm just using text and not any designated section or title, `titlesec` doesn't seem too necessary at this time.

This doesn't work as desired because of the return space after the horizontal line:

```
\begin{flushleft}
\Large{CptZpBrngn\\}
\nointerlineskip\hrulefill
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushright}
\small{1234 Fake St.}
\end{flushright}
```

Putting another `\nointerlineskip` after `\hrulefill` causes an error (! You can't use `\prevdepth` in horizontal mode.) and after the `flushleft` section it doesn't do anything.

Edit:
Thanks go to David for leading me to the answer.

This is the formatting that ended up looking best to me:

```
\begin{flushleft}
{\large CptZpBrngn\\}
\nointerlineskip\hrulefill\\
{\raggedleft \small 1234 Fake St.\par}
\end{flushleft}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
\Large CptZpBrngn
\hrule
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushright}
\small 1234 Fake St.
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

Note the  rule touched the letters, you could add a blank line then `\vspace{2pt}` to add some space. Note that size change commands like `\Large` and `\small` do not take a `{...}` argument and should always include the end of the paragraph in their scope otherwise the line spacing will be incorrect.

Or version with no vertical space at all

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

{\raggedright
\Large CptZpBrngn
\hrule
\par
\raggedleft
\small 1234 Fake St.
\par}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but please notice the spacing above the address.  This is what I would like to remove (tops of letters as close to the bottom of the line as the bottom of the name is to the top of the line).

Comment: @CptZpBrngn That is from the flush environments, you can use `{\raggedleft the address\par}` to have no vertical space

Comment: @CptZpBrngn see 2nd version in updated answer